# Iterated return in constructors

Tags: python, elementtree

Why does this example return only the last child attributes, how can I get them all?

Input:

```
    <root c1="A" c2="B"</root>
    <root c1="A" c2="C"</root>
```

Script:

```
    data = ElementTree.parse("./test.xml").getroot()
    def getLetters(data):
        for child in data:
            if child.attrib['c1']:
               c1 = child.attrib['c1']
            if child.attrib['c2']:
               c2 = child.attrib['c2']
        return c1, c2
    print getLetters(data)
```

The result is always overwritten and I get the last child.

I have tried yield but still have the same problem:

```
       yield c1, c2
   generator = getLetters(data)
   for i in generator:
       print i
```

Comment: You can only `return` once, in this case at the end of your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't i use constructors in this case? what should i use?

Comment: @user2598997 I don't see a constructor in your code.

Comment: You haven't got a "constructor" here. They're not a thing in Python anyway. What do you think a "constructor" is?

Comment: Of course we may suggest to use `yield` instead of returning a data structure, but it may complicate things even more

Comment: I've been reading this tut: https://openclassrooms.com/courses/apprenez-a-programmer-en-python/premiere-approche-des-classes. He calls defs as constructors. Sorry, it's in French.

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you not call `__new__` a constructor?

Comment: @user2598997 no he doesn't, he calls the `__init__` method a constructor, which it kind-of sort-of is. But he clearly refers to functions and methods more generally throughout that post, and points out that `__init__` is a specifically named function with a special purpose.

Comment: I used __init__ and worked also. I will put it with the answers. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your function is iterating over all pairs of elements you happen to have in your xml. Once you finished iterating, you return whatever values c1 and c2 are eventually assigned (which might not even be from the same child, the way your code is written), which are going to be either the last pair of elements or c1 and c2 corresponding to their last occurrences in that xml (because you did not do anything with the previously obtained pairs of values).

You have two approaches here:

1) create a structure, e.g. a list of tuples or, better yet, dictionaries, and keep adding your (c1, c2) elements there:

```
def getLetters(data):
    result = []
    for child in data:
        # use other default values here if more suitable 
        c1 = None
        c2 = None
        if child.attrib['c1']:
           c1 = child.attrib['c1']
        if child.attrib['c2']:
           c2 = child.attrib['c2']
        result.append({'c1':c1, 'c2':c2}) # append your next entry as a mini-dictionary  
    return result

for entry in getLetters(data):
    print 'c1', entry['c1'], 'c2', entry['c2']
```

2) use yield which might be more efficient way to process a large chunk of data, because you don't have to wait until it gets all processed before passing it further.

```
def getLetters(data):
    for child in data:
        # use other default values here if more suitable 
        c1 = None
        c2 = None
        if child.attrib['c1']:
           c1 = child.attrib['c1']
        if child.attrib['c2']:
           c2 = child.attrib['c2']
        yield {'c1':c1, 'c2':c2} # yield the mini-dictionary for every child
    # no return needed here

# you can process the output in the same way:
for entry in getLetters(data):
    print 'c1', entry['c1'], 'c2', entry['c2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class getLetters:
          def __init__(self):
              self.c1 = child.attrib['c1']
              self.c2 = child.attrib['c2']

    for child in data:
        i = getLetters()
        c1 = i.c1
        c2 = i.c2
        print c1, c2
```